# Connect from Excel 2007 to Oracle via ODBC (Windows7 x64)

Tags: excel, oracle, odbc

I have a Windows 7 64 bit and Excel 2007 32 bit.
I need to connect with Oracle DB by ODBC.

How can i create the above connection?

I installed 32bit client:
instantclient-basic-nt-12.1.0.2.0 and 
instantclient-odbc-nt-12.1.0.2.0,

I created necessary environment paths (PATH, ORACLE_HOME, TNS_ADMIN) and I add ORACLE_HOME to variable PATH in system path.

When I'm trying to create DSN in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe I'm getting an error nr 126: system can not find a file SQORAS32.dll in %ORACLE_HOME%...

Any ideas?

Comment: You said the `PATH` is set. But what about `ORACLE_HOME` ?

Comment: ORACLE_HOME too... in %ORACLE_HOME% is my specific path which is C:\Oracle\instantclient_12_1

Comment: Could you open a console and echo `%PATH` and `%ORACLE_HOME` ? Does they match with your installation path ? Have you located the `SQORAS32.dll` file somewhere, or is it really missing from your system (it _should_ be part of _ODBC Instant Client_) ?

Comment: Yes, they do:
ORACLE_HOME=C:\Oracle\instantclient_12_1
PATH=C:\Oracle\instantclient_12_1;
SQORAS32.dll is not missing. It is located in ORACLE_HOME... I checked also in register and everything is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created ODBC connection!

The problem with error nr 126 still appears when I'm trying to create connection using driver "Oracle in instalclient_12_1", but when I'm using driver "Microsoft ODBC for Oracle" it works ok.